# Error al importar relativamente un paquete en Python (ImportError)

Tags: python, python-3.x, vscode, excepciones, packages

He visto muchos en muchos foros acerca de esto, pero aún sigo sin solucionar el problema de importación de paquetes de forma relativa. 
Dicho eso comienzo con mi inconveniente.
Tengo dos paquetes (main y clases) los cuales en el main tengo que poner el módulo principal y en el paquete clases sus respectivas clases.
La jerarquía sería así:
 **Mi proyecto** 
|->`__init__.py`
|->**clases**
|-->`__init__.py`
|-->`auto.py`
|->**main**
|-->`__init__.py`
|-->`__main__.py`

Desde el módulo main, tengo que importar la clase Auto, comprendida en el módulo auto.
Por lo tanto mi importación es esta:

```
from ..clases.auto import Auto
```

Pero resulta que cuando quiero ejecutar el programa, sale una excepción de tipo ImportError indicando que el intento de importación relativa no tiene paquete principal conocido.

[image: Error de Importacion de paquetes de paquetes paralelos]

Desde ya, muchas gracias por su atención. Espero que no esté duplicado. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el comando con que intentas arrancar la aplicación y desde qué carpeta lo ejecutas?

Comment: Hago click derecho sobre el módulo main y selecciono ejecutar archivo de python sobre la terminal.

Comment: El problema es que, ya que toda tu carpeta (la que contiene `clase` y `main`) es un paquete, no puedes ejecutar `main` así desde dentro del paquete. Tienes que abrir una terminal, subir un nivel con `cd ..` (de modo que estés en la carpeta por encima de la que contiene a `clases` y `main`, digamos que se llama `mi_app`) y desde ella harías `python -m mi_app.main`

Comment: Y si borro el __init__.py del proyecto inicial, podría ejecutarlo? Porque no me deja.

Comment: No, el `__init__` es necesario porque si no las sub-carpetas no se entienden como módulos (dentro del paquete)